# SFSE: Salesforce Stack Exchange

Tags: discussion

I am a developer at heart, and as a developer I love acronyms :)

When ever I am referring to the site, I find myself unsure what to call it. So I end up typing Salesforce Stack Exchange.

What I am proposing is an accepted acronym for refering to the site: **SFSE**

I don't expect it to get much recognition outside of the stackexchange, but least on the site I can use SFSE and people will know what i'm talking about

I have written this post to elict discussion and hopefully if there is a consensus, a post to link to if someone enquires what SFSE means

Comment: I've just been using SE, which at least on here seems specific enough, but I'm fine either way.

Comment: I like SFSE...there was a similar [question](http://meta.salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/75/what-abbreviation-should-be-used-to-refer-to-this-site/77).

Comment: @PeterKnolle I completely missed that! Seems that SFSE was popular in that thread as well

Comment: @jkraybill that is another good suggestion, site specific yes, but most of the time it is on this site that I want to refer to this site

Comment: Why is this question closed as a dupe? The original was a VERY long time ago and had no clear answer. Seems like a totally legit conversation to have now; it's not like there are too many conversations on meta these days anyway.